# Programmatically push APK to system/app

Tags: android, adb, root

I want to programmatically push an APK to system/app, on a rooted device. I've tried the following code, but `push` doesn't appear to be a command on Android. How can I modify it to work?

```
  public static void copyApkToSys(){
    Process process;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes("mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system\n");
        out.writeBytes("push /data/shareData/a1.apk /system/app\n");
        out.writeBytes("mount -o remount,ro -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system\n");
        out.writeBytes("exit\n");  
        out.flush();
        process.waitFor();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

If I use the following code, the app only appears after rebooting the device:

```
public static void copyApkToSys(){
    Process process;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes("mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system\n");
        out.writeBytes("cat /data/shareData/a1.apk > /system/app/a1.apk\n");
        out.writeBytes("mount -o remount,ro -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system\n");
        out.writeBytes("exit\n");  
        out.flush();
        process.waitFor();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

edit:  if i use cat ,then use the follow code,but i cannot start my activity

```
public static boolean startApk(String packageName, String activityName) {
    boolean isSuccess = false;

    String cmd = "am start -n " + packageName + "/" + activityName + " \n";
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        isSuccess = waitForProcess(process);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return isSuccess;
}
```

It seems that there a difference between `push` and `cat` as pushing the app through adb gives the result I would like. How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no command `push`. There are a very limited number of posix commands on Android, but `cat` should be able to copy the file in that fashion. What's your reasoning in not using it?

Comment: if i use cat,but i cannot start my activity. i want  to copy or push the apk to system,and then start it.

Comment: That's likely because Android doesn't know a new application has been installed. It will need to inspect the app manifest to understand which intents it can receive, which happens when installing an app in the conventional way. I'm not sure how to trigger that behavior, but rebooting the device will likely work.

Comment: if  i use adb push at the cmd,then called startApk,all is ok.but i first cat,then startApk,it is not used.

Comment: Indeed, that's odd. Perhaps `push` triggers some action to check for changes in system apps? I hope somebody can provide a little more insight into this as I'm, too, curious.

Answer (score -1):

try with command "`mv -R`", like the Linux command